# How to apply text alignment to a datagrid row on the LoadingRow event from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row, text-alignment

I have a datagrid which is populated at the runtime. I want to highlight some data.
For that I use the LoadingRow event.

[image]   [image]

The code below works:

```
dtg_ExecutionTimes_PpDescriptions.LoadingRow += (sender, args) =>
{
    int rowNum = args.Row.GetIndex();
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dtg_ExecutionTimes_PpDescriptions.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowNum);
    switch (m_ListCells[rowNum].Arm)
    {
        case CfgPartPrograms.eArm.ARM1: break;
        case CfgPartPrograms.eArm.ARM2:
                row.Foreground = Brushes.GreenYellow; <-------THAT WORKS :-)
                row.HorizontalAlignment = row.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;<-----THAT DOESN'T WORK :-(
                break;
                case CfgPartPrograms.eArm.ARM12: row.Foreground = Brushes.LightSalmon; break;
                default:
                break;
    }
};
```

I have also tried with style but for some reasons I get no effect

```
var MyStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridRow)) { Setters = { new Setter(TextBlock.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right) } };
row.Style = MyStyle;
```

Thanks in advance
Patrick

Comment: Thanks but I don't know what tags you are referring to. Could you please explain me?

Comment: Your question title was _"C# WPF how to apply text alignment to a datagrid row on the LoadingRow event from code behind"_ meaning that it included tags for C# and WPF.  See the bottom section of the [tagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for more examples of title formats to avoid.

Comment: Does `row.HorizontalAlignment = row.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;` work if you split it up into two different assignments?

Comment: No and not even putting row.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        row.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;

Comment: @Patrick: You should set the `ElementStyle` of the column to right-align the cell value.

Comment: @mm8 sir i think Element horizontal style of column will set all values in that column to center. and he wants only specific values in center (i guess).

Comment: if you want to change alignment of specific values then a trick would be setting left margin.

Comment: @mm8 please re-read the last part of the code I posted, isn't that what I did?

Comment: @Patrick: No, you are setting the `Style` property of the row.

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain no I can't do that

Comment: @Patrick: See my answer for an example of how to set the `ElementStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `ElementStyle` of the column to right-align the cell value.

If you want to right-align only values with a `Foreground` of `Brushes.GreenYellow`, you could add a `DataTrigger` to the `Style`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="..." Header="Part program decscription" Width="200">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foreground,
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="GreenYellow">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Thank you but as I said I can only use code behind and not xaml. And with the column it works easily I have to do it with the row

Comment: You may create a style programmatically using [XamlReader.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse?view=netframework-4.8). I don't understand what you mean by "row". The `TextBlock` is in a cell, i.e. a specific column of a row. You use the `DataTrigger` to apply it to specific rows only.

Comment: I have to act in the whole row

Comment: Then you apply the same `Style` to all columns. The result and solution is the same.

Comment: Please see my edit: pic1 witht the red arrow is not ok, pic2 is ok instead. Pic2 is what I would like.

Comment: What mm8 has told is solution of your problem. you apply the style to last column and in that column that particular value with that specific color will be rightly aligned.

Comment: I don't understand. I only have to move the cell with the arrow not the whole column. Alternatively the whole row but never the whole column

Comment: the above solution should move only 1 value P2 to right as you want . Why ? because it says give me the LAST WHOLE COLUMN and find the value with GREEN COLOR and then shift that VALUE ONLY to right.

Comment: if there are more than > 1 values with same GREEN color then those all values will become rightly aligned.